# Error when using openmap function (OpenStreetMap package) in R

Tags: r, openmap

I want to get a map based on a set of longitude and latitude coordinates using openmap.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
map <- openmap(c(43.46886761482925,119.94873046875),
    c(33.22949814144951,133.9892578125),
        minNumTiles=4)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Error in if (substring(type, 1L, 4L) == "http") type else match.arg(type) : 
  the condition has length > 1
```

Comment: Please add `type="osm"` to `openmap()` function.

Comment: Thanks, I discovered that, but what is the reasos? Shouldn't be one as default? Also, I get an error when using other types.

Comment: Don't know. Please raise a issue on their repository: https://github.com/ifellows/ROSM.